# Kaplan-Maier curve censoring events not displaying when a ties between censor and event time

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, survival-analysis

We noticed a difference between how R (`survival` package) and SAS (or `survminer`) display KM curves censoring events. When an event occur at the same time as a censoring one the `+` mark is not displayed in the graph. The `survminer::ggsurvplot` function display the censoring event correctly like SAS.

Am I missing something here? How do I get plot.survfit to display all the censoring 'events'?

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

df <- data.frame(time=c(4,6,8,11,15,15,17,18,19), 
                 cens=c(0,0,1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)) 

mod <- survfit(Surv(time, !cens) ~ 1, data=df) 

# plotting with the survival package does not show a mark at time = 15 
plot(mod, mark=1, mark.time = TRUE, conf.int = FALSE)
```

[image: survival plot]

```
# plotting with survminer or SAS display the mark at time 15.
ggsurvplot(mod, data = df, conf.int = FALSE)
```

[image: survminer plot]

Answer (score 2):

found the solution.

```
plot(mod, mark=1, conf.int = FALSE, mark.time=mod$time[mod$n.censor > 0])
```